# Метод расширения статический

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

VS 2015 принуждает переназначить класс как статические без понятных для меня причин

> Ошибка    CS1106  Метод расширения должен быть определен в неуниверсальном статическом классе

в чем причина проблемы, раньше класс исполнился как не статический

Comment: Вообще-то это ограничение языка такое.

Comment: Дак студия же четко написала проблему не понятно то что?

Comment: Чего в друг он начал это требовать, я этот класс не трогал

Comment: @SergD29 неважно, трогали вы класс или нет, но методы расширения в C# можно объявлять только в статических классах

Comment: спасибо за помощь, исправил, VS живет своей жизнью

Answer (score 2):

Взято из MSDN

> Методы расширения определяются как статические методы, но вызываются с
>   помощью синтаксиса обращения к методу экземпляра.  Их первый параметр
>   определяет, с каким типом оперирует метод, и параметру предшествует
>   модификатор this.  Методы расширения находятся в области действия,
>   только если пространство имен было явно импортировано в исходный код с
>   помощью директивы using.
>   В приведенном ниже примере показан метод
>   расширения, определенный для класса System.String.  Обратите внимание,
>   что этот метод определяется внутри невложенного, неуниверсального
>   статического класса.

```
 namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Получил такую проблему когда скопировав функцию со stackoverflow обнаружил в ней валяющийся посреди аргументов **void**. Видимо случайно кто-то при ответе добавил.

Убрал его и проблема ушла.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]